# Can't connect ESP8266 to Arduino IDE

Tags: c++, c, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-esp8266

I am doing a project where the goal is to collect temperatures with Dht22 and send them in .json through Esp8266. For this I am using Arduino products. Today I was able to connect Arduino Uno and Dht22 to Arduino Ide and collect values by the sensor. The next step is to take care of the network. I followed several tutorials but I always get an error.
I'm using this (see bellow) code copied in create.arduino.cc:

```
#include <DHT.h>;
#define DHTPIN 7     // what pin we're connected to
#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302)
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE); //// Initialize DHT sensor for normal 16mhz Arduino

float temp; //Stores temperature value

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  dht.begin();
}

void loop()
{
    temp= dht.readTemperature();
    Serial.print("Temp: ");
    Serial.print(temp);
    Serial.println(" Celsius");
    delay(10000); //Delay 2 sec.
}
```

The Board is configured with "Arduino/Genuino Uno" and the port is COM4. I can get the temperature values this way.
Now to configure Esp8266, from what I realized, I have to change the board to Generic ESP8266 Module. I added the URL

```
http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json
```

in File>Preferences>Settings. The problem is that I always get this error:

```
esptool.py v2.6
2.6
esptool.py v2.6
Serial port COM4
Connecting.....______....._______....._______Traceback(most recent call last):
File "C:\Arduinol5\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.52\tools\upload.py", line 25, in <module> esptool.main(fakeargs)
File "C:/Arduinol5/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.52/tools\esptool.py", line 2653, in main esp.connect(args.before)
File "C:/Arduinol5/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.52/tools\esptool.py", line 468, in connect raise FatalError('Failed to connect to %s: %s' % (self.CHIP_NAME, last_error))
esptool.FatalErro: Failed to connect to ESP266: Timed out waiting for packed header
esptool.FatalErro: Failed to connect to ESP266: Timed out waiting for packed header
```

I've done several Internet searches to find a solution but nowhere to find an answer. For this reason I resort to asking here. If you have any advice I would appreciate it. I hope to have clearly stated the subject. Thank you!

Comment: is the esp8266 in bootloader/flashing mode?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't think so... Is that a criterion to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For esp module to boot, reset or wake up, you need to keep IO2 high and IO15 pulled down.
Pull down IO0 to boot into flashing mode.